# Expression Evaluator

Tags: java, indexof, string-length

I have to write a program to do the following:

> Calculate the following expression for any value of the x, and save the result into a variable of type double.
>
> Next, determine the number of digits to the left and to the right of the decimal point in an unformatted result.
>
> [Hint: You should consider converting the type double result into a String using the static method `Double.toString(result)` and storing it into a String variable. Then, on this String variable use the `indexOf()` method from the String class to find the position of the period and the `length()` method to find the length.  Knowing the location of the decimal point and the length, you should be able to determine the number of digits on each side of the decimal point.]
>
> Finally, the result should be printed using the class `java.text.DecimalFormat`  so that to the right of the decimal there are at most four digits and to the left of the decimal each group of three digits is separated by a comma in the traditional way. Also, there should be at least one digit on each side of the decimal.

I know I did not display the expression I have to calculate for `x`, but I have that part of the program working.

I'm stuck on trying to find out the number of places on each side of the decimal.

The output should read as follows:

> Enter a value for x: 1
> Result: 1.6528916502810695
> digits to left of decimal point: 1
> digits to right of decimal point: 16
> Formatted Result: 1.6529

I tried using the `indexOf()` and `length()` methods.
I keep receiving errors.

Here is my code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner; 
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;

 public class ExpressionEvaluator 
 {
      public static void main (String[] args)
      { 
       Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
       double x,part1,part2,part3,part4,result;
       String value = "";
  
  
       System.out.print("Enter a value for x: ");
       x = userInput.nextDouble();
   
       part1 = (5 * Math.pow(x,7));
       part2 = (4 * Math.pow(x,6));
       part3 = (Math.pow((part1 - part2),2));
       part4 = (Math.sqrt(Math.abs(3 * Math.pow(x,5))));
       result = (Math.sqrt(part3 + part4));

       System.out.print("Result: " + result);
     
       value = Double.toString(result);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Please explain the purpose of this math that you are doing on `x`

Comment: So did you call `value.indexOf(".")` and `value.length()` at the end?  And what did you do with the results of those two calls?  Also, did you think about the case where the value gets converted in scientific notation, with an `E`?

Comment: I did do both of those. But i wasnt sure how to take the result of those methods and apply it in a way that I could get it to read out the # of characters on either side of the decimal

Comment: And yes i still get the correct output for one with scientific notation

Comment: It's a math problem. Not a programming problem. You have the total length of the string (including the decimal) and the position of the decimal. The prompt explicitly says you *should be able to determine the lengths*

Comment: And the math to x is an arithmetic expression. I wasnt sure how to type it out on here that is why i did not include it.

Comment: Well, if there's a `.` but no `E`, then isn't the number of digits to the left of the `.` the same as `value.indexOf(".")`  and the number of digits to the right the same as `value.length() - value.indexOf(".") - 1` ?  It's entirely different in the case where there's an `E`.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. I didnt think about value.indexOf(".") being equivalant to the number of digits on the right.

Comment: Also if there is an E(##) then it should just be included in the count for numbers to the right of the decimal place.

Comment: No, if there's an `E`, you have to do it completely differently.  You'll need to parse out the number that comes after the `E`.

Comment: Please read our policy about [homeworks](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that indexing starts at zero.

Take your string `1.6528916502810695` as an example.

Where is the `.`? At the second position of the string, which is the first index. How many characters from the left did it take to find the `.`? Just one.

Therefore, `int left = value.indexOf(".");`

This satisfies the problem statement

> use the indexOf() method from the String class to find the position of the period

Now, how many characters are to the right of the `.`? Well, that's just the full length of the string - (the `.` and everything to the left of it). You already calculated how many characters are to the left of the `.`

In other words, `int right = value.length() - (1 + left);`

And that covers the remainder of the hint

> the length() method to find the length. Knowing the location of the decimal point and the length, you should be able to determine the number of digits on each side of the decimal point.

Comment: This won't work if `x` is large enough that `toString` will use scientific notation.

Comment: Agreed, but this is how the problem statement was asked to implement the algorithm. A proper course would likely have test cases for acceptable inputs

Answer (score 0):

You can get number of decimals to right and left using these methods.

```
import java.util.Scanner;    
import static java.lang.StrictMath.log10;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String x1;
        System.out.print("Enter a value for x: ");
        x1 = userInput.next();
        int length = x1.length();
        double x = Double.parseDouble(x1);
        System.out.println("Digits to the left of the decimal point:" + (int) Math.ceil(log10(x)));
        System.out.println("Digits to the right of the decimal point:" + (length - 1- (int) Math.ceil(log10(x))));
    }
}
```

test

```
Enter a value for x: 123456.78
Digits to the left of the decimal point:6
Digits to the right of the decimal point:2
```

Comment: While a good alternative, I don't think that's how the question is supposed to be solved.

Comment: This won't work if `x` is large enough that `toString` will use scientific notation.

Comment: @DavidWallace Please review my bugfix. Does it work now?

Comment: I don't think so.  The whole point of the question is that the OP gets the `double` value by doing some calculations, not by typing a String in at a prompt.